How to set the type for Class Variable
In the below code, the accountType can be Individual or Joint. In my automation test codebase, some classes will set accountType to Individual and some will set accountType to Joint and run tests.
Every line where I set the accountType to Joint and access coApplicantName, it shows me a warning  :
Property 'coApplicantName' does not exist on type 'Individual | Joint'. Did you mean 'applicantName'?.
I am also unable to navigate to any of the Joint class Property/methods using CMD+Click. This also applies to TrustAccount properties
I'm able to overcome this by setting the type (a.accountType as Joint).coApplicantName = "Dave", but this needs be done every line where I'm accessing the Joint class property. In my actual code, this will be more than 100 lines where I would have to specify the type across different classes.
Another workaround I tried is const jointAcc = a.accountType and then access it using jointAcc.coApplicantName, but since this is needed across multiple files, I would have to create this new variable across multiple files
Is there any way I can set the type at the top level to avoid specifying the type at each line
class AccountDetails
{
    accountType: Individual | Joint | TrustAccount;
    accountType: number;
}

class Individual {
   applicantName: string
}

class Joint extends Individual{
   coApplicantName: string
}

class TrustAccount extends Individual{
   TrustName: string
}
let a = new AccountDetails()

function JointAccountTest(){
   a.accountType = new Joint()
   a.accountType.applicantName = "John"  //No Warning is shown
   a.accountType.coApplicantName = "Dave" //Warning Shown
}


Why don't you use constructor to set the  accountType?

You can create the Joint object first then assign it to the accountType.
function JointAccountTest(){

  const joint = new Joint();
  joint.applicantName = "John";
  joint.coApplicantName = "Dave";

  a.accountType = joint;
}

